# Source Control through Xcode not working "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.", cannot complete username and email

Tags: xcode, version-control

Some time ago an answer to my same problem was released, unfortunately I've not been able to fix it through that. Many recommended that in preferences->SourceControl -> Git I would change user and email, though this is not possible, since every time I type something in there it "disappears" as soon as I click anywhere else. I'm NOT using git through terminal, just through XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it's a temporary bug several other developers have encountered. There is little do to about it, we can just wait until Apple fixes it in the next version of XCode.